# How do you interface with a ^0.4.x ERC721 inside of a ^0.7.6 contract?

Tags: erc-721, nft

It seems to me that pre 0.5 NFTs are not compatible with more modern solidity versions. I am trying to use the contract written on ^0.7.6 to call "safeTransferFrom(address,address,uint)" from the ^0.4.x contract, and it's causing reverts, even when I try to do a low level call.

The 0.4.x NFT is already deployed. I am trying to deploy a 0.7.6 contract that can make calls to this contract.

Here is the interface of the 0.4.x contract I'm trying to interface with:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

/**
 * @title ERC721 Non-Fungible Token Standard basic interface
 * @dev see https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-721.md
 */
contract ERC721Basic {
  
  function ownerOf(uint256 _tokenId) public view returns (address _owner);
  function exists(uint256 _tokenId) public view returns (bool _exists);
  function approve(address _to, uint256 _tokenId) public;
  function getApproved(uint256 _tokenId) public view returns (address _operator);
  function setApprovalForAll(address _operator, bool _approved) public;
  function isApprovedForAll(address _owner, address _operator) public view returns (bool);
  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) public;
  function safeTransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) public;

}
```

Here are the important parts of the function I want to call from my 0.7.6 contract:

```
    function _executeOrder(
        address nftAddress,
        uint256 assetId,
        uint256 price,
        bytes memory fingerprint
    ) internal returns (Order memory) {
        ERC721BasicInterface nftRegistry = ERC721Interface(nftAddress);

        nftRegistry.safeTransferFrom(order.seller, _msgSender(), assetId);
    }
```

The issue is, what should **ERC721Interface** be defined as in my 0.7.6 contract? Clearly, the interface written in 0.4.21 is not compatible with 0.7.6 (external function modifiers). I tried calling **safeTransferFrom** using a more modern ERC721 interface on the 0.4.21 NFT but the transactions were reverted. This is correct behavior I'm assuming, since the interface is different.

Comment: Can you add some code from both ends. And answer Lauri's question about deployment.

Comment: Done. Please take a look and let me know if anything should be added or changed

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this has nothing to do with Solidity versions. The `safeTransferFrom` function in Solidity really means `keccak256("safeTransferFrom(address,address,uint256)")` for the Ethereum Virtual Machine. But let's not get lost with details.

When you call `safeTransferFrom`, the caller of this function needs to have been approved via the `approve` function, like so: `approve(futureCaller, tokenId)`. When this is done, you can confirm who is approved for transfer with `getApproved(tokenId)`.

Now, when you call `safeTransferFrom` from the `_executeOrder` in your own 0.7.6 contract, **the caller is your 0.7.6 contract**. So your contract needs to be pre-approved by the token owner.

So the solution is to first do (example in Javascript here):

```js
await the_0_4_Nft.methods
    .approve(my_0_7_6_contract_address, the_token_id)
    .send({ from: token_owner_address });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write an interface with the 0.7.6 version. The interface doesn't care with what Solidity version the target contract is compiled with - it simply states what functionality the target contract has. You can basically write the interface in any version you want (although best to write it with a version which explicitly supports interfaces).

I just changed the version number and replaced `public` with `external`. So your interface could look like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.6;

interface ERC721BasicInterface {
  
  function ownerOf(uint256 _tokenId) external view returns (address _owner);
  function exists(uint256 _tokenId) external view returns (bool _exists);
  function approve(address _to, uint256 _tokenId) external;
  function getApproved(uint256 _tokenId) external view returns (address _operator);
  function setApprovalForAll(address _operator, bool _approved) external;
  function isApprovedForAll(address _owner, address _operator) external view returns (bool);
  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) external;
  function safeTransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) external;
}
```

Comment: The 0.4.x contract is already deployed. How do I create an interface for 0.4.x on 0.7.6? 0.4.x doesn't even have interfaces right?

Comment: Just the same way you'd create an interface for a 0.7.6 contract. The interface doesn't care about what compiler version was used in the contract which is being used by the interface, it works the same for all compiler versions.

Comment: Can you take a look at the code I've added? I don't think it's possible to do what you're suggesting

Comment: Edited my answer